# Why do HTML div elements rotate weird on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, safari

I'm trying to create a pie chart. On desktop (Google Chrome), this pie chart code works as usual and the `left` and `right` divs rotate fine. However, opening this code on a mobile device (specifically iPhone 11 running Safari) something weird happens. Right as the page loads on a mobile device, the rotating divs stick out of their parent element `circle` for a moment, mid-rotation, before eventually going back to normal.

```js
let left = document.getElementById("left");
let right = document.getElementById("right");

function spinPieChart() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    left.style.opacity = 1;
    left.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
  
    setTimeout(function() {
    right.style.opacity = 1;
    right.style.transform = "rotate(60deg)";
    }, 250);
  }, 10);
}

spinPieChart();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  #circle {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: tomato;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    transform-origin: right;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s, transform 250ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  
  #right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    transform-origin: left;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s, transform 250ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  #cover {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: tomato;
    left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="cover"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hmm, not at all sure but it kind of sounds like maybe the CSS is still being processed or that the HTML is drawn before the CSS is fully processed, is it an option for you to test creating the actual HTML elements and inserting them into them DOM just as `spinPieChart` is being run?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen went and tried this. seems like it gave the same results though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can draw the same using `svg` and `circle` elements and apply the CSS for animation (eg. @keyframes).

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

circle {
    fill:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  stroke-width:31.8309886184;
  stroke-dasharray: 0,0,0,100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 25;
  -webkit-animation: pie1 3s 1 ease both;
  animation: pie1 3s 1 ease both;
}

.pie1 {
  stroke:lightblue;
}

.pie2 {
  stroke:tomato;
  -webkit-animation-name: pie2;
  animation-name: pie2;
}

/* 1st pie is 70% */
@-webkit-keyframes pie1 {
  50%,100% {stroke-dasharray: 70,30,0,0;}
}

@keyframes pie1 {
  50%,100% {stroke-dasharray: 70,30,0,0;}
}

/* 2nd pie is 30% */
@-webkit-keyframes pie2 {
  50%,100% {stroke-dasharray: 0,70,30,0;}
}

@keyframes pie2 {
  50%,100% {stroke-dasharray: 0,70,30,0;}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 63.6619772368 63.6619772368">
    <circle class="pie1" cx="31.8309886184" cy="31.8309886184" r="15.9154943092" />
    <circle class="pie2" cx="31.8309886184" cy="31.8309886184" r="15.9154943092" />
  </svg>
</div>
```